# Excel filter list based on other list and output rows

Tags: excel, list, filter, bioinformatics

Note in advance: I'm sorry if my language is biology-oriented. I'm a biologist.

So I have this big dataset where each row is a gene and each column contains values for this gene at different timespoints.

What I wanted to do is make a subset of these genes, using another genelist I have. Is there a way, in excel, to filter out only the genes I want so I can export their values?

It looks a bit like this:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=827ceea

So what I want to do is filter the huge list of genes and their expression values through a much smaller genelist that I have.
The output would be an image similar to the one above, only with way less genes (the one in the pic has about 40k, but of course you can't see that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the Advanced Filter functionality.

You need to add a few blank rows above the data table, where you can enter the expressions that you want to filter by. Advanced filter can be set up to include several values and can be set up to look at several columns.

The Excel Help has intro and samples for working with Advanced Filter.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I got the advanced filter to work.
But, now it's also displaying gene names that just contain the one in the filter.
For example, it displays "FASLG" because "FAS" is in the criteria (which it shouldn't). Is there a way for setting it to exact matches only. I don't see an option for that.

Comment: Instead of `FAS` use `="=FAS"` as the search criterion.